# R Studio Disable Popups during Knit

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I'm on R Studio version `1.2.5033` and whenever I knit an R Markdown document I get popups of all my data frames that are generated on the fly. These take the main focus of my desktop environment and are unnecessary (for my needs). How do I disable these data frame popups?

I'll paste my hacked screen grab of a popup, they only appear for a split second. But make working on anything else in my desktop environment impossible as they constantly grab desktop environment focus. I'll also post my current settings as it seems none of them would disable these popups.

---

**EDIT** - it looks like this happens whenever I have `... %>% View()` in my pipe, which I use a lot. Removing the `%>% View()` probably "fixes" this, but I want to keep the `%>% View()`s in my chunks as they makes working in the R Notebook easier for me.

I'd almost put this in as an R Studio settings feature request but it may be utilized by so few users as to not be worth it to put in the dev time.

[image: rso2]

[image: rso1]

Comment: You should definitely remove the `View` calls: they don’t belong into a reproducible workflow. You can still use them *inside the interactive console* while writing your Notebook. If you didn’t save the result in a variable, you could do `View(.Last.value)`.

Comment: You may be able to use an if() statement to switch view() on or off? Define ‘view <- ‘yes’ ‘ at the top of your code, then in pipe something like ifelse(view==‘yes’, view(), empty), where empty is a function that does nothing.